Association between individual treatment & covariates and aggregated survey outcome (per 1 covariate only)
I would like to assess whether employees who perform training (Treatment T) have a better perception of growth opportunities (Outcome Y) in a company given covariates X such as:

Gender, Age range
Sub direction, Direction, Executive direction
City / Country
Seniority range, contract type

The Outcome Y (growth opportunity score) is measured through an HR survey on a 11-point Survey Scale (NPS scale ranging from 0 to 10).
As this is a survey, the participation is not 100%.
We only get Y at aggregated levels for each covariates X (see above).
In other words, we get a mean (without variance) for each covariate value.
Example for covariate country:

8.8 for country UK
6.2 for country US

The treatment T is defined as the sum of training hours before the survey (preceding 12 months).
This amount is known at individual level and we do have the values of all covariates X (see above) at individual level.

What would be the modeling approach in that case with individual treatment and independant variables (covariates) and aggregated outcome for values of 1 independant variable only (ex: by country).

What if I would like to see the impact for a set of covariates, more than 1. What would be the modeling apporach if any (maybe to many assumptions here)?



Hi, just to clarify - what does it mean that you "only get Y at aggregated levels for each covariates X"? If we forget covariates for a moment and just consider T and Y, do you have an individual value of outcome Y for each of your participants?

And how many countries do you have?

Hi Sointu,
I don't have any individual value of outcome for each of my participant.
Instead, I have:

30 mean scores (1 for each country: the mean of all individual within the country)
8 mean scores (1 for each seniority range:


OK! In that case you have data with N=30 and you need to also average your predictors within countries and run the model with country as the observational unit. You can't use the individual level data in your model if you only have country-level values for your outcome.
